# convert from a color back to a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, colors, hex, parseint

I have an existing fn that does the following:

```
    public GetColor = (argb: number) => {

        var a = 1;// (argb & -16777216) >> 0x18; // gives me FF


        var r = (argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10;
        var g = (argb & 0x00ff00) >> 0x8;
        var b = (argb & 0x0000ff);
        var curKendoColor = kendo.parseColor("rgba(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + "," + a + ")", false);
```

I would like to know the function I would need to return that back to a number.

for example if i have AARRGGBB of (FFFF0000)   and I would like to get back to the number version that toColor would have derived from.

I would be ok with the unsigned version of the return number or the signed version. Unsigned would be -65536 but the unsigned would be fine as well (not sure what that number would be off top of my head now)

I tried to do this but the attempts all end out at 0 which i know is not correct:
            colorSend |= (parseInt(this.Color.substr(0,2),16) & 255) << 24;
            colorSend |= (parseInt(this.Color.substr(1, 2), 16) & 255) << 16;
            colorSend |= (parseInt(this.Color.substr(3, 2), 16) & 255) << 8;

the parseInt gives me the 255,0,0 that I think I would expect but the & and the shift logic does not seem correct because & zeros the integers out thus the result was 0

Comment: Well, looking at the code to go the one way, what's *your* attempt at the code to go the other way? E.g., what's your specific question about doing that? Right now the question reads as "Please write this function to do the converse of this code for me." which isn't what SO is for.

Comment: I had tried to do something like

Comment: sorry, yes I added my first attempt which by all accounts did not give what I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to get something that seems to work for me.   I am simplifying it a bit but for the ARGB i can do something like

```
val = "0xFFFF0000"
val = parseInt(val, 16)
if((val & 0x80000000) != 0)
{
   val = val - 0x100000000;
}
```

So for example for Red with an A of FF I would get-
-65536 or with unsigned I can omit the last part.

Answer (score -1):

Actually it's pretty easy. You just have to understand what the HEX values mean.
In the hexadecimal system each number from 10 to 15 is represented by the letters A to F. The numbers lower ten are normal numbers 1 - 9. So if you want to convert 11 into hex it would be 0B. Because you need no number below 11 (0) and the letter B represents 11. If you read a little bit about the hex system, you should be able to write you new function very easily ;)

Comment: Yes thanks for your input, I understand what hex is and how the numbers are represented but this does not address the function i need enough to write the reverse of the function above.   I also know I can use parseInt with the base 16 to get, for example the r value converted over to "256" and similar for the other G and B.   but were the process needs to go from there is my issue.